# Как просуммировать в конце все собранные массивы в один?

Tags: python, scrapy

Автоматизирую поиск ссылок scrapy. Ссылки на одной странице он находит и пагинация также работает как надо, только вот в конце нужно просуммировать все собранные массивы(с ссылками через кому) в один массив.

## Вопрос: Как все собранные массивы в конце обьеденить в один?

```
class SplashSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spide'
    start_urls = ['url']

    def parse(self, response):
        href = response.css('a.item::attr(href)').extract()
        yield href
        next_page = response.css('a.next::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Что значит "ссылка через кому"?

Comment: @strawdog, не уверен, но подозреваю, что имелось ввиду: `с ссылками через запятую`. ЗЫ "запятая" в украинском - "кома"  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь модулем itertools

```
import itertools

first_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
second_list = [5, 6, 7, 8]
summ = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([first_list, second_list]))

print(summ)
```

Получится один большой список [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

UPD
Так же можно это реализовать как предложил @strawdog

```
summ = [*first_list, *second_list]
```

Вывод будет такой же, как и в первом случае: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Comment: `summ =  [*first_list, *second_list]`, чтоб не из пушки по воробьям

Comment: @strawdog, тут скорее всего как из минигана) спасибо за ещё один способ