# Как просуммировать в конце все собранные массивы в один? (с другого аккаунта)

Tags: python, scrapy

Компьютер с почтой успешно навернулся так что пришлось создать новый аккаунт.
Я заводил вот этот вопрос -
[Как просуммировать в конце все собранные массивы в один?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/999552/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd)

Отвечу - все ссылки через запятую выглядят так - [https:// url.com, https:// url2.com и т.д]

Также у меня все массивы возвращаются не в переменной а обычной yield. Если соединять их с помощи itertools, то не подскажете как автоматически вывод yield переводить в динамически сгенерированные переменные?

## EDIT 1

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как просуммировать в конце все собранные массивы в один?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/999552/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что при утере учётной записи надо её востоновить, а не задавать вопросы создавая новую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метода соеденения всех массивов не нашел но решил это простым `.replace` заменяя сначала все квадратные скобки на запятые. Потом вставляю в массив в виде `start_urls = [links]`.

```
f = open('text.txt', 'r')
data = f.read()
f.close()

newdata = data.replace("[", ",").replace("]", ",").strip(",")

f = open('text.txt', 'w')
f.write(newdata)
f.close()

actualdata = actualdata.replace(",,", ",").replace(",\n,", ",").replace(' ', '')

f = open('text.txt', 'w')
f.write(actualdata)
f.close()
```

> links - переменная с ссылками из файла

Разделил в 2 подхода потому что у меня из ниоткуда при 1 заходе появляется \n в некоторых местах рандомно

Так как файлы огромные то пока еще не тестировал подход но должен работать так что думаю вопрос исчерпан

Answer (score 0):

Любую функцию-генератор можно "собрать" через (де)итерирование:

```
def ttt():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i

res = list(ttt())
print(res)
```

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Простая конкатенация списков в python делается через распаковку отдельных списков в общий:

```
first_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
second_list = [5, 6, 7, 8]
res = [*first_list, *second_list]
print(res)
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Comment: Конечный файл выглядит как `['https:// url1.com' , 'https:// url2.com' , ... ] ['https:// urln.com' , 'https:// urln+1.com']`. Таких массивов несколько сотен и вряд ли я буду им всем давать переменные. Надо что бы выглядело в итоге так ['https:// url1.com', 'https:// url2.com', ... , 'https:// urln.com' , 'https:// urln+1.com']

Comment: попробовал `   def list(links(переменная с массивами)):
        all=[]
        for lst in links:
          all.extend(lst)
        return all`

Comment: но оно просто разделяло каждый елемент массива на отдельный елемент('['[',' " ','h','t','t' и т.д.)

Comment: во-первых, никогда не давайте своим переменным и функциям зарезервированные имена (например, list). во-вторых: если у вас есть уточнения по вашему коду - добавьте их в вопрос, потому что их комментариев ничего не понятно.